# How to get the exit code of program invoked by system call?

Tags: c++

For example, Program *a.out*:

```
int main()
{
    return 0x10;
}
```

Program *b.out*:

```
int main()
{
    if(system("./a.out") == 0x10)
       return 0;
    else
       return -1;
}
```

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system), the return value of `system()` is *implementation-dependent*. Thus, the attempt of program b.out is obvious erroneous.

In the case above, how can I get `0x10` instead of an undetermined value? 
If system call is not the right tool, what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: It is implementation defined which means you need to look up the documentation for example on *unix or unix like environment* `man system` would tell you the details you require.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667095/c-how-can-i-get-return-value-of-command-passed-to-execl

Comment: `system` is a bit heavy-weight for this. Do you really want to launch a shell for this? That's a security no-no if the calling code is every going to run as root, or with an odd environment.

Comment: @NicholasWilson That's a good point. Would you describe the suggest way to do this?

Comment: @southp Just fork and exec. You should only be using `system` if you really, really need to use shell syntax (eg `system("./a.out | anotherapp 2>/dev/null")`) and can't be bothered to set up the required pipe or redirection in code.

Comment: Usually you can get the return value of a program after running it, by printing `$?` in the shell. At least on most Unix like systems

Comment: Side note: `system()` is a security *nightmare*. Don't ever use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting `man system`:

```
The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.   fork(2)  failed),  and  the
return  status  of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is
in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command
will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).
```

You need to use `WEXITSTATUS` to determine the exit code of the command.  Your `b.c` needs to look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main()
{
    int ret = system("./a.out");
    if (WEXITSTATUS(ret) == 0x10)
      return 0;
    else
      return 1;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps more portably, `if (WIFEXITED(ret) && WEXITSTATUS(ret) == ...)`?

Comment: How would you do this if you're using Visual C++? We don't get to use `<sys/wait.h>`

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a unix system, you should use fork execve and wait.

Here a sample code of your case:

```
Program b.out:

int main()
{
    return 0x10;
}

pRogram a.out:

int main()
{
 int pbPid = 0;
 int returnValue;
 if ((pbPid = fork()) == 0) // Fork create a child process
 {
  // Only executed in child process
  char* arg[]; //argument to program b
  execv("pathto program b", arg);
  exit(34);
 }
 else
 {
  // Only executed in parent(original) process
  waitpid(pbPid, &returnValue, 0);
 }
 returnValue = WEXITSTATUS(returnValue);
 // returnValue will be 34 if exeve failed
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you handle error returns from execv? Is exit(-1) actually good enough, given all the strange WEXITSTATUS stuff? (sry. coming from windows world, where this is all infinitely more obvious)

Comment: I updated the code, I hope it's more obvious now :)

Answer (score 1):

system call is good, but you have to pay attention of your command to execute.
I run something like 'myscript.sh p1 p2 p3 | tee /mylog' and got always ok back.
The problem is the pipe. system always returned the exit code of the last command which always worked and not the result of the myscript.
So, only use pipe in the command to execute if you don't expect exit code of first command.

Answer (score 0):

To get the completion status of the first process from the pipe, you can use this approach:

```
int ret;    
ret = system("bash -c 'myscript.sh p1 p2 p3 | tee /mylog; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}'");
printf("retcode = %i\n", ret>>8); // or printf("retcode = %i\n", WEXITSTATUS(ret));
```