# Getting return value of external program

Tags: c, linux, exec, return-value

I wrote a program `p1.out` that returns me a value according to its arguments.
 I ran this program from another `p2.out` using execv function and I want to get the return value of `p1.out`.
How can I do it? 
I know I cant check `if(execv(...)==1)`

Comment: You cannot use `execv` as it will replace `p2.out` with `p1.out`.  You should consider using [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html).  The link contains example code.

Comment: I didnt understand the question. p2.out returns a value, I want to print it to terminal

Comment: Guess it is answered already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2667095/1079907). You should be using `waitpid()` with your `p1` being child process since `exec` family cannot return.

Comment: @SSC I forgot to write in the question but i'm using fork. to run the p2.out with the child

Comment: @Sunil Bojanapally thank you. I'll look into it