# Fork and execlp, how to differentiate the status and print state accordingly

Tags: c, fork, exec

I am referring to this question - [How to get the return value of a program ran via calling a member of the exec family of functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667095/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-a-program-ran-via-calling-a-member-of-the-exec-fa/2667166#2667166) from SO as I am trying to attempt similar actions.

Instead of the `execl` command, I am using `execlp` command. As my code, is supposed to take in a list of command line arguments, eg. `./myCode /bin/ls /bin/date` in the event even if one of the argument is wrong, for example `/bin/lsa`, it is printing out the wrong line - Child Exit Code is 0.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main()
{
    int number, statval;
    int child_pid;
    printf("%d: I'm the parent !\n", getpid());
    child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid == -1)
    { 
        printf("could not fork! \n");
        exit( 1 );
    }
    else if(child_pid == 0)
    {
        execlp("/bin/lsa", "/bin/ls" ,(char *) NULL);

        // error
        printf("ERROR - Cannot run command\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PID %d: waiting for child\n", getpid());
        waitpid( child_pid, &statval, WUNTRACED);
        if(WIFEXITED(statval))
            printf("Child's exit code %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(statval));
        else
            printf("Child did not terminate with exit\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the terminal output:

```
119: I'm the parent !
PID 119: waiting for child
ERROR - Cannot run command
Child's exit code 0
```

What are some of the other ways that I can do to improve the last portion of the if-else code block? Using the example `./myCode /bin/lsa /bin/date`, I am trying to achieve the following output:

```
Command /bin/lsa cannot be executed

<display output of /bin/date>
Command /bin/date is a success
```

Comment: Apparently you should return a non-zero code from the child in case of error, if your parent is expecting it.

Comment: But your child's exit status *is* zero when its `execlp()` fails.  If you want it to be something different in that case then have the child `return` the wanted status or pass it to `_exit()` after printing the error message.

Comment: Hi @EugeneSh., are you perhaps referring to the same that as Ian has mentioned below?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, any chance if you could elaborate more or show me a simple code snippet? Sorry about that as I am still brand new to this realm of forking

Comment: @dissidia, if your `execlp()` call in the child returns at all, then the control flow eventually reaches the `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.  That is then what the parent will observe as the child's exit status.  If you want the parent to observe a different exit status in that case then you must cause a different value to be returned, or, equivalently, you must directly exit the child with a different status, as calling, say, `_exit(1)` would do.

Comment: Also, I took comments in your code to indicate that you already understood this, but just in case, it is essential to appreciate that `execlp()` and the other exec-family functions do not return at all when they succeed.  They *can't*, because their effect is to replace the code then running in the calling process with another program, which is entered at its normal entry point.  Nothing is left to return to.  It follows that `execlp()`'s return value (if it returns) has nothing to do with the exit status of the program it (fails to) execute.

Answer (score 1):

After the child prints "ERROR - Cannot run command\n", it falls through to the `return 0;` statement, causing the process to exit with status code 0. You can return some other small positive value to change the exit code.

Running an unknown command in the Bash shell seems to set Bash's `$?` variable to 127, so perhaps that is a reasonable choice of return value.

Comment: I tried implementing in the `exit(127)` after the said line, still I am getting the same result. Whether I used `/bin/ls` or `/bin/lsa`, it will still tells me both commands are a success, alongside with `ERROR - Cannot run command`

Comment: @dissidia I just tried that myself (adding `exit(127);` after `printf("ERROR - Cannot run command\n");`) and the parent printed `Child's exit code 127` as expected. Perhaps you forgot to recompile it?

Comment: You were right, my bad!